# Create excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 worksheets. In worksheet 'MONDAY' i have a column 'D' which have the names. eg NEW, TRIAL, JIM,  etc. Through column 'H' of 'MONDAY'! I have the $ amount.

In worksheet 'TOTAL'! I want B19 to show the sum amount of ('MONDAY'! column 'H') only IF ('MONDAY'column 'D') has the specific name ie 'JIM' in the same row.

Worksheet 'TOTAL' have the names also written as reference through column 'A' ie A19 has 'JIM'

Comment: In future please note that basic formula questions should be asked at Super User - these are not programming.

Answer (score 3):

in B19 of sheet *Total*, use the `SUMIF` function

```
=SUMIF('MONDAY'!$D:$D,$a19,'MONDAY'!$H:$H)
```

Check the detail on the function on [office.microsoft.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx) to understand how it works.